# "Adb devices" command pops up a command prompt window and doesn't show the devices connected to the PC

Tags: android, sdk, appium

Any help on this would be appreciated.

I've been researching about this `adb` error and the different solutions posted aren't working for me.
As the titles says, when I execute on `cmd: adb devices` it shows up for 1 sec a new command prompt without any information and at the end it returns to the original cmd window without any results of the device connected to my computer.

Some days ago it was working fine until some awful windows updates were installed and I began to experience this sdk problems.

Also, with this problems I've been facing it's very difficult to run `Appium` which is my goal right now to make some automated tests on Android devices.

> PD: I've installed-reinstalled the SDK, Java, Eclipse, etc..  The
>   system variables are added on the PATH.  I run the programs as an
>   admin too.  SDK manager is up to date with the updates.

Thank you everyone for your help and support. 
Regards.

Comment: Check in your Settings--> Developer options--> USB debugging. And enable that.

Comment: I'm already have usb debugging enabled :). I reinstalled the phone's driver too but without success to fix this problem.

Comment: Try to install PdaNet+ from this site [PdaNet+](http://pdanet.co/a/) . connect via usb. It will install Pda to your attached device. Allow it. This solution worked for me. Hope it will help you.